# PysimpleGUI button callback for scapy to sniff network traffic

Tags: python, scapy, pysimplegui

I am using pysimpleGUI to create a GUI..I want to use the the button sniff to carry out a ARP scan using Scapy then print the details of this either in the Output or Multiline element in pysimpleGUI could someone guide me how to do this

At the moment the ARP scan function works in commandline but does not print it out on the Output or Multiline element.

```
# ===================================================================================================================================
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Import Modules Section
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import subprocess
import os
import sys
from scapy.all import Ether, ARP, srp
from scapy.all import *

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define Constants Section
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


sg.SetOptions(icon=None,
              button_color=('blue', 'white'),
              element_size=(None, None),
              margins=(None, None),
              element_padding=(None, None),
              auto_size_text=None,
              auto_size_buttons=None,
              font=None,
              border_width=None,
              slider_border_width=None,
              slider_relief=None,
              slider_orientation=None,
              autoclose_time=None,
              message_box_line_width=None,
              progress_meter_border_depth=None,
              progress_meter_style=None,
              progress_meter_relief=None,
              progress_meter_color=None,
              progress_meter_size=None,
              text_justification=None,
              text_color=None,
              background_color=None,
              element_background_color=None,
              text_element_background_color=None,
              input_elements_background_color=None,
              element_text_color='blue',
              input_text_color=None,
              scrollbar_color=None,
              debug_win_size=(None, None),
              window_location=(None, None),
              tooltip_time=None,
              )


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define Modules Section
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Functions
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def arp_scan():
    _range = raw_input("Enter the Target Range: ")
    _interface = raw_input("Enter the network interface: ")
    ip, ntBits = _range.split('/')
    ip_addresses = []
    st_bit = ip.split('.')[3:4][0]   #Since it's an IPv4
    for n in range(1, int(ntBits)+1):
        eval_ip = ".".join( ip.split('.')[:-1] ) + '.' + str(n)
        ip_addresses.append( eval_ip )

    for ip in ip_addresses:
        _pkt = Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff") / ARP(pdst=ip)
        ans, unans = srp( _pkt, iface=_interface, timeout=0.1, verbose=False)
        for snt, recv in ans:
            if recv:
                print("Host Alive: %s - %s" % (recv[ARP].psrc, recv[Ether].src))

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Pre-Processing Section
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
joblist = []
tool = dict()
tool['input-width'] = 144
tool['input-heigt'] = 10
tool['output-width'] = 140
tool['output-heigt'] = 30
tool['output-font'] = 'Courier'
tool['output-font-size'] = 10
tool['opm-flow-manual'] = 'None'
tool['opm-resinsight'] = 'None'
tool['edit-command'] = 'None'
vers = 'v1'

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define GUI Section
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mainmenu = [['File', ['Open', 'Save', 'Exit']]]

flowlayout = [[sg.Output(background_color='white', text_color='black',
                         size=(tool['output-width'], tool['output-heigt']),
                         key='_outflow_', font=(tool['output-font'], tool['output-font-size']))]]

loglayout = [[sg.Multiline(background_color='white', text_color='darkgreen', do_not_clear=True,
                           key='_outlog_', size=(tool['output-width'], tool['output-heigt']),
                           font=(tool['output-font'], tool['output-font-size']))]]

mainwind = [[sg.Menu(mainmenu)],
            [sg.Text('Available Hosts')],
            [sg.Listbox(values=joblist, size=(tool['input-width'], tool['input-heigt']), key='_joblist_',
                        font=(tool['output-font'], tool['output-font-size']))],

            [sg.Button('Start', key='_start_sniff_'),
             sg.Button('Stop')],
            # sg.Button('Delete Job'),
            # sg.Button('Clear Queue', key='_clear_queue_'),
            # sg.Button('Load Queue', key='_load_queue_'),
            # sg.Button('Save Queue', key='_save_queue_')],

            [sg.TabGroup([[sg.Tab('Text', flowlayout, key='_tab_output_',
                                  title_color='black', background_color='white'),
                           sg.Tab('URL', loglayout, key='_tab_outlog_',
                                  title_color='black', background_color='white', border_width=None),
                           sg.Tab('Images', loglayout, key='_tab_outlog_',
                                  title_color='black', background_color='white', border_width=None)]],
                         title_color='black', background_color='white')],

            # [sg.Button('Run Jobs', key='_run_jobs_'),
            # sg.Button('Kill Job', key='_kill_job_'),
            # sg.Button('Clear', key='_clear_'),
            [sg.Button('Exit', key='_exit_')]]
# [sg.Text('')]]

window0 = sg.Window('CTTool - Cleartext Tool ' + vers).Layout(mainwind)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define GUI Event Loop, Read Buttons, and Make Callbacks etc. Section
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
while True:
    #
    # Read the Form and Process and Take appropriate action based on button
    #
    button, values = window0.Read()

    if button == '_clear_':
        if '_tab_output_' in str(values):
            window0.Element('_outlog_').Update('')

    if button == '_start_sniff_':
        try:
           arp_scan()
        except:
            pass

    if button == '_exit_' or button == 'Exit' or button is None:
        text = sg.PopupYesNo('Exit CTTool?')
        if text == 'Yes':
            text = sg.PopupYesNo('Are You Sure You wish to Exit CTTool?')
            if text == 'Yes':
                break

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Post Processing Section
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
window0.Close()

# ===================================================================================================================================
# End of CTTool.py
# ===================================================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your layout.  Your Tabs use the same key which is not allowed.  You've also attempted to reuse an element.  These will generate popup error messages that will identify the problem.  `loglayout` is one of them.  I copied it to get rid of the problem.

As far as integrating your `arp_scan` code, you'll want to modify it by removing the user interface calls and instead add them to your main GUI window.  When you call the scan, pass in the values that are now being input via `raw_input`.  Also pass in the element you're planning to output to.  Rather than use print, use `update` with a `Multiline` element.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback could you give me an example of how I can pass the arp_scan function to update in the multiline element?

Comment: You change the "print" statement in your code to multiline.update(value) where multiline is the multiline element.  As I said, pass into that function everything it needs.  Pass in the input values instead of collecting them in the function and pass in the element you want to output to.